# Import documents to a particular/targeted shard in Mongo Shard Cluster

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I'm new to MongoDB, however I have setup a shard cluster with 3 replica sets. Each replica set has 2 mongod instances. I have a separate config server and 1 mongos instance.

**I wanted to try whether it's possible to import documents to a particular/targeted shard, when the collection is not shard enabled.** (As far as I know, we can't control in which shard the collection will get saved when importing is done via mongos instance)

Hence, I imported the documents using below command, and it was successful (followed [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption-mongoimport-host));

```
mongoimport --db NormalTestDB --collection TestDams --host <replSetName>/<hostname1><:port>,<hostname2><:port> --jsonArray --file “<path_to_json>”
```

(I used a particular replica set name in `<replSetName>`)

Now when I try this simple query `db.TestDams.find().count()` in mongos shell (by connecting to NormalTestDB), it returns 0. But if I try the same query by directly connecting to the Primary of the relevant replicaSet, I get 14603.

Is there any way that I could sync? or is there a way to use `mongoimport` targeting a particular shard??

Answer (score 1):

(Aside: You should generally have 3 nodes in a replica set rather than 2.)

When you [enable sharding on a database](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/enableSharding/#dbcmd.enableSharding) you can specify the primary shard. Unsharded collections will be stored on that shard. So, you can define one database per shard with each configured to have a distinct shard as the primary shard.

Alternatively if you set up [zones](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/zone-sharding/) you can specify which values of shard keys are to be stored on each shard. Then by inserting appropriate values you'd have the data stored on the shards you want.

You should be performing all operations on your sharded cluster through one of the `mongos` nodes, not like you have done writing directly to shard `mongod`s.

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm using MongoDB 3.6 and the option to define the primary shard seems to be available in MongoDB 4.2.2 (and 4.0.14) onwards. Also, I need to have the collections in the same DB. Sorry for not mentioning that in the question. Further, most probably all the collections will have the same shard key (eg; _id), although the data in documents are slightly different.

Comment: Use zone sharding then.

Comment: And _id is more often than not a poor choice of shard key.